# prevent 2 users from logging in to the same account

Tags: php

I have a login script that uses no SQL because the server does not allow it.
How can I prevent users from logging in on the same account from different machines/browsers?
I have tried the solutions that i have found here on stackoverflow, but none of them worked.
Here is my PHP:

```
    <?php 
session_start(); 


define('DS',  TRUE); // used to protect includes
define('USERNAME', $_SESSION['username']);
define('SELF',  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );

if (!USERNAME or isset($_GET['logout']))
 include('login.php');  

// everything below will show after correct login 
echo '            <p>Te-ai conectat ca ';
echo $_SESSION['username'];
echo '</p>
            <p><a href="?logout=1">Inchidere sesiune</a></p>
            <tr><td>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <table style="width: 80%;">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 23px;">
<td style="width: 27%; height: 23px;">&nbsp;Canal&nbsp;1&nbsp;si&nbsp;2&nbsp10s</td>
<td style="width: 18.7131%; height: 23px;"><audio controls="controls" preload="none"><source src="http://t22sys.noip.me:9300/;stream.mp3" type="audio/mp3">Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio></td>
<td style="width: 27%; height: 23px;"> <a href="http://t22sys.noip.me:9300/listen.pls" style="color:black"><button type="button">Asculta in player extern</button></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
';
?>
```

the login PHP is as follows:

```
 <?php defined('DS') OR die('No direct access allowed.');
 $users = array(
 'user'=>'pass',
);
if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
   $_SESSION['username'] = '';
   header('Location:  ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
   }
   if(isset($_POST['username'])) 
{
   if($users[$_POST['username']] !== NULL && $users[$_POST['username']] == $_POST['password']) 
   {
       $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
       header('Location:  ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
       }
       else
       {
           echo "<p>Eroare la autentificare</p>";
           }
}
echo '<form method="post" action="'.SELF.'">
<p>Autentificare membrii (Canal 1 si 2 fara delay, 128kbps)</p>
<p><label for="username">Utilizator:</label> <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" /></p>
<p><label for="password">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Parola:</label> <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Autentificare" class="button"/></p>
</form>';
exit; 
?>
```

Comment: this code does not make a lot of sense, people are logged in if the posted username matches the session username. but how did the username get in to the session in the first place?

Comment: If you need user sessions and cannot use databases, you're going to have a bad time :)

Comment: File based sessions are still standard @Max

Comment: All right @Dagon, I didn't knew that :)

Comment: *"from logging in to the same account"* - so how/where is all this stored if you're not using a database?

Comment: seems like we're all talking amongst ourselves here, I'm out of this "going nowhere lounge.

Comment: @fred-ii
the users are stored here:
    $users = array(
    'user1'=>'pass',
    'user2'=>'pass'
    );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that duration of your session is 15 minutes. Just in case.

You have no db access. I think you have to store additional info in separate file, eg. logged.txt.

Proposed structure:

```
admin,2016-12-04 21:30
anotheruser,2016-12-04 21:30
```

where lines contains login (unique username), and date - `logged_to` equivalent

For every request we have to parse this file by `file_get_contents` or `getcsv` then keep its data in array. Every change or page reload require to parse file, update data, and save everything in that file.

When someone is logged in, update `logged_to` field to future date - +15 minutes from current time. Of course every page reload when user is logged should update this field again with future date: +15 minutes from current time.

When user is logging out, just remove line with his username from this file.

Of course when user tries to log in, you have to check if user exists in `logged.txt` file or, if exists, if logged_to date is earlier that current

Comment: he claims he has no database access, so what users table?

Comment: @Dagon
i am using a string for storing user info:
$users = array(
 'user'=>'pass',
);

Comment: @piotr, thank you for your answer sir, but unfortunately i;m not a code writer, i've just collected the bits for this script from all over the net.
can you rewrite the code for me
I was thinking of associating the username with his IP when he is logged on and delete the association as soon as he logs off
and if another person tries to connect with that username while the session is open, login will be denied.

Comment: Find me on LinkedIn, we may talk about this